# Java constructor fails to work with varargs

Tags: java

I have the following enum which has a number of constructors:

```
public enum Route
{
   HOMEPAGE("", null, UserType.GUEST);

   Route(String baseName, String langFile, Entity entity) {}
   Route(String langFile, Entity entity)  {}
   Route(String langFile, UserType... availability) {}
   Route(String baseName, String langFile, UserType... availability) {}
}
```

In this case, I'm pretty clearly calling the 4th constructor when I define `HOMEPAGE`. But the problem is, I'm getting the error: `Cannot resolve constructor Route(java.lang.String, null, com.foo.UserType)`.

If I either remove the varags from the constructor, i.e so it looks like:

```
   Route(String baseName, String langFile, UserType availability) {}
```

Or if I change the null when defining `HOMEPAGE`, i.e:

```
   HOMEPAGE("", "", UserType.GUEST);
```

Then it works. But it doesn't make sense to me why that is. Why doesn't it detect that I'm calling the 4th constructor?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that `null` could be either a `String` or a `UserType`. So:

```
HOMEPAGE("", null, UserType.GUEST);
```

would match either the third or fourth constructor. Casting the `null` to a `String` would result in the fourth constructor being selected:

```
HOMEPAGE("", (String) null, UserType.GUEST);
```

Comment: I see... tricky. Thanks for clarifying it. If I cast the null to String, will my constructor still receive null as the value of that argument?

Comment: Just a clarification that I do not understand, since the third constructor only takes two arguments, and the call is clearly passing three arguments... How can the call be mistaken for the third constructor?

Comment: @Gladhus, the third can take more than two due to the varargs.

Comment: Oops, can't believe I didn't see that. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

It is correct that it does not know which constructor to pick, your call is:

```
Route(String, null, UserType)
```

This can surely not refer to the top two constructors.

It can however refer to `Route(String, UserType)`, as the `null` could be of type `UserType`.
It could also refer to `Route(String, String, UserType)`, as the `null` could be of type `String`.

There is your conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Because null can either be a String or a UserType :

```
Route(java.lang.String, null, com.foo.UserType)
```

matches with both methodes :

```
Route(String langFile, UserType... availability) {}
Route(String baseName, String langFile, UserType... availability) {}
```